# Counting process equality for linear rank test under AFT model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, survival, censoring, accelerated-failure-time

I am currently reading through the paper:

*Estimating Regression Parameters Using Linear Rank Tests for Censored Data* - A.A. Tsiatis, Annals of Statistics 18(1): 354-372, 1990.
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-18/issue-1

and I am trying to verify a seemingly simple equality statement however I am having difficulty understanding why the statement is true. At the bottom page page 358, the author gives a set of two equality statements for the function $S_N(\beta)$. I can verify the second equality (just above (3.2)) and I can verify line (3.2) do not understand how the inclusion of (3.3) retains the equality of the original statement. Any explanation for why line (3.3) can be included would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The details for the statements given above are listed below:

Consider the accelerated failure time model $\log(T_i) = \beta' \boldsymbol{Z}_i + \epsilon_i$ for $i = 1, 2, ..., N$ where $T_i$ is the failure time, $\beta$ is a vector of unknown parameters, $\boldsymbol{Z}$ is a matrix of covariates and $\epsilon_i$ is a random error term that are i.i.d. with common unknown cdf $F$. Consider a set of right-censored failure time given by:
$$(X_i, \Delta_i, \boldsymbol{Z}_i)$$
where $X_i = \min(T_i, C_i)$ and $\Delta_i$ is the censoring indicator. Let $N_i(u) = I(X_i \leq u, \Delta_i = 1)$ and let $Y_i = I(X_i \geq u)$ denote the failure time and at-risk and counting processes respectively and let $\bar{Z}(u) = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N} Z_j Y_j(u)}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} Y_j(u)}$. Let $T^*$ be some fixed upper bound. Starting with
$$S_N(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_{-\infty}^{T*} dN_i(u + \beta Z_i) \left\{ Z_i - \bar{Z}(u, \beta)\right\}$$
the author claims:
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_{-\infty}^{T^*} dM_i(u + \beta Z_i) \left\{Z_i - \bar{Z}(u, \beta)\right\}$$
$$ + \sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_{-\infty}^{T^*} \left\{ \lambda(u + \beta Z_i) - \lambda(u) \right\} du Y_i (u + \beta Z_i) \left\{ Z_i - \bar{Z}(u, \beta)\right\}$$
where $M_i(u + \beta Z_i) = N_i(u + \beta Z_i) - \int_{\infty}^{u} \lambda(x) Y_i(x + \beta Z_i) dx$.

**Question**: In the summation representation of $S_N(\beta)$, the first term follows from standard counting process arguments. Why is it possible to include the second term in the summation representation?

Comment: Thanks for adding the equations and the link to the paper.

Comment: This seems to represent the decomposition of the counting process $N_i$ into the sum of a (stochastic) martingale $M_i$ (giving the first term) and a (predictable) compensator (giving the second term). Section 2.2 of [Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842) provides a reasonably accessible introduction to that decomposition. Is there something else in question here?

Comment: In the first equality, yes, the counting process $N_i$ can be expressed as $M_i$ evaluated at $u + \beta Z_i$ however in the expression of $M_i(u + \beta Z_i)$, the hazard function is evaluated at $u$ and not $u + \beta Z_i$. My concern is with the component of the equality attached to $\lambda(u + \beta Z_i)$.

Comment: I need to think about this more, but the issue of using the hazard $\lambda(u)$ instead of $\lambda(u+\beta Z_i)$ appears first on page 356. This comes from testing the general hypothesis $\beta=\beta_0$ via replacing the observed event times $X_i$ with the residuals between observed and predicted event times, $X_i-\beta_0 Z_i$. There's no problem for testing $\beta=0$. I suspect that the answer comes from how the at-risk indicator $Y_i (u+\beta_0 Z_i)$ affects the compensator term.

Answer (score 2):

The [cited paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-18/issue-1) (Eq. 1.1) considers regression models having predictors $Z$, individuals $i$, and coefficients $\beta$, of the general form:

$$ T_i = \beta' Z_i + e_i,$$

where the $T_i$ are subject to right censoring (last observed value $X_i$, the lower of $T_i$ and the censoring value) and the $e_i$ are identically and independently distributed errors.

This general form can provide the setup for a parametric accelerated failure time (AFT) model, if $T_i$ is the logarithm of time and the $e_i$ have a corresponding underlying distribution (e.g., minimum extreme value for Weibull, Gaussian for log-normal). It's not, however, limited to parametric AFT models or to survival times.

To handle right censoring, the paper examines a counting process $N_i$, which is decomposed into a sum of a (stochastic) martingale $M_i$ and a (predictable) compensator. The compensator in a survival model typically takes the form ([Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842), page 20):

$$\int_0^t \lambda_i(s) Y_i(s) ds ,$$

where $Y_i(s)$ is the at-risk indicator for individual $i$ at time $s$.

Until the last observation time for individual $i$, at $s=X_i$, the individual's compensator is the cumulative hazard of events. It is constant thereafter, as $Y_i(s) =0$ for $s > X_i$. It is the same whether an event or right censoring occurs at $s=X_i$. An event in the counting process $(dN_i(X_i)=1)$ versus right censoring $(dN_i(X_i)=0)$ at that last observation is subsumed in the martingale.

The question is why in formulas 3.2 and 3.3 the counting process $(N_i)$, martingale $(M_i)$, and at-risk indicator $(Y_i)$ are evaluated at a different argument $(u + \beta_0 Z_i)$ than the hazard function, $\lambda(u)$.

The reason can be gleaned from text near the initial definition of the martingale on page 536 for a single covariate $Z$:

$$M_i(u +\beta_0 Z_i)=N_i(u +\beta_0 Z_i) - \int_{-\infty}^u \lambda(x) Y_i(x+\beta_0 Z_i) dx. $$

In particular:

> We can easily generalize to test the hypothesis $\beta=\beta_0$ by replacing the times $X_i$ with the residuals $X_i-\beta_0 Z_i$.

This paper is thus concerned with the distribution of the errors $e$ (estimated by the residuals) under the hypothesis $\beta=\beta_0$ rather than the distribution of event times $T$. Under that hypothesis, an event at time $\beta_0 Z_i$ means $e_i=0$. An earlier event time means a negative residual, a later event a positive residual. For a right-censored observation at time $X_i$, the residual under that hypothesis is correspondingly right-censored at $X_i-\beta_0 Z_i$.

The paper refers to the distribution of errors as being in "error term time" on page 356. The hazard function $\lambda(x)$ in the definition of the martingale is thus with respect to the distribution of the errors $e$ in "error term time" rather than of the event times $T$.

Put another way, under the hypothesis $\beta=\beta_0$, the counting process at event time $u + \beta_0 Z_i$ provides information about the distribution of errors $e$ at "error term time" $u$. It reduces to the usual form for estimates of the distribution of event times $T$ when $\beta=0$ and the distributions of $T$ and $e$ are the same.

A similar distinction between the distribution of event times and the distribution of residuals comes up in a way to evaluate the choice of parametric distribution in an AFT model. A Kaplan-Meier plot of right-censored residuals can be compared against the theoretical survival curve (complement of the cumulative distribution function) for the chosen parametric distribution. See for example Figure 18.10 of Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/parsurv#sec-parsurv-assess).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I understand how (3.2) comes about through the martingale argument as well as the subtracted term in (3.3) as the summation is equal to 0. My main concern is with the term $\lambda(u + \beta Z_i)$ in (3.3) as the summation cannot pass over it and the integration does not simplify. If the statement were that this equality is true at $\beta = 0$, then I would agree however, equality does not appear to hold for $\beta$ away from $0$.